# C# Newtonsoft - Deserialize JSON into concrete based on property name

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I've got a JSON coming in that I'd like to deserialize into a class `A`; one of the fields is an array of abstract class `B` (which has a few concrete implementations). Is it possible to deserialize the abstract-class array correctly **without** building a custom JsonConverter? Ideally, something native to JSON.net and not verbose, e.g. with `TypeNameHandling.All`... but I haven't got that particular route to work.

I do **not** have access to the JSON at serialization-time (if I did, `TypeNameHandling` would work great), but only at deserialization-time.

To be concrete:

```
public class A  // the top-level class to deserialize
{
    public B[] arr;
    // other members...
}
public abstract class B
{
    // ...some fields...
}
public class C : B 
{
    // a concrete implementation of B
}
public class D : B 
{
    // another concrete implementation of B
}
```

And I receive a JSON that may look like:

```
{
  "arr" : [
   {
     // a C object
   },
   {
     // a D object
   }
  ]
}
```

I know you can effectively do something like this really cleanly with XML deserialization using the below; I'm pretty much looking for something similar in JSON.

```
// tells the deserializer to deserialize the object with field name "C" as a 
// class C, and field name "D" as a D
[XmlElement("C", Type = typeof(C))]
[XmlElement("D", Type = typeof(D))]
public B[] arr;
```

Comment: Do you know whether the JSON will have items of C or D?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No. The array could have just Cs, just Ds, or some combination of Cs and Ds

Comment: And do you get them separately (like in different methods)? I mean if you know at compile time whether they will be C or D

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Unfortunately not. The entire JSON will come in one go.

Comment: Interesting question.  Without a custom converter to inspect the properties I'm not sure how you'd do it.

Comment: You either need to use [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) which means modifying the JSON to indicate the type, or like Justin says, a custom converter which is a bit hacky.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @DavidG and Justin. I know you can do it with XML pretty cleanly (as shown at the bottom of my edited question) -- too bad there doesn't seem to be an equivalently-nice JSON solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are unable to modify the JSON to use [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) you need to create a custom converter that examines the properties to determine which type to return. Let's say you had your derived classes looking like this for example:

```
public class C : B
{
    public string CProperty { get; set; }
}

public class D : B
{
    public string DProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You could have a custom converter class that looks like this:

```
public class BConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, 
        object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jobject = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (jobject.ContainsKey("CProperty"))
        {
            return jobject.ToObject<C>(serializer);
        }

        if (jobject.ContainsKey("DProperty"))
        {
            return jobject.ToObject<D>(serializer);
        }

        throw new Exception("Um, this is some other type!");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type type) => type == typeof(B);
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) 
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now you can deserialise like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, new BConverter());
```